# Unresolved reference: AlertDetails

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I´m trying to create an intent in kotlin. Here is the code:

```
private val notificationIntent = Intent(this, AlertDetails::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
private val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
```

The problem is calling java class (AlertDetails::class.java) show the unresolved reference error.
I have tried to change gradles. My build.gradle have the following plugins that I have seen in other questions:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Use the name of your actual class instead of `AlertDetails`, so try replacing `AlertDetails::class.java` with `TheNameOfYourClass::class.java`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the name of your Activity, for example:

```
MainActivity::class.java
```

You can find more details here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation#build_a_pendingintent_with_a_back_stack